# List view load faster

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I'm using a ListView but it load too slow and i need it to load faster, not sure how i can make the adapter load each of the listviews one by one, is it possible?
here is my code:

```
                ArrayList<String> myTripOrigin = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> myTripDestiny = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> myTripHour = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList <boolean[]> myTripSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Boolean> myTripBools = new ArrayList<Boolean>();


                for(int i = 0; i<response.body().size();i++)
                {
                    myTripBools.add(response.body().get(i).isRol());
                    myTripOrigin.add(getAdress(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(response.body().get(i).getOrigin_lat()),Double.parseDouble(response.body().get(i).getOrigin_lng()))));
                    myTripDestiny.add(getAdress(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(response.body().get(i).getDestiny_lat()),Double.parseDouble(response.body().get(i).getDestiny_lng()))));
                    Date date = new Date((Long.parseLong(response.body().get(i).getArrival_time()))*1000L);
                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
                    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                    String formatted = format.format(date);
                    myTripHour.add(formatted);


                }

                //Send the array to constructor
                ListAdapter userAdapter = new CustomAdapterRoute(getApplicationContext(), myTripOrigin,myTripDestiny,myTripHour,myTripSchedule,myTripBools);
                ListView userListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRoute);
                userListView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

            }
```

here is the custom adapter Route:

```
public class CustomAdapterRoute extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private ArrayList<String> itemFrom = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemTo = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemHour = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<boolean[]> itemSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Boolean> itemRole = new ArrayList<>();

    //Send arrays
    public CustomAdapterRoute(Context context, ArrayList<String> stringArray, ArrayList<String> stringTo, ArrayList<String> stringHour, ArrayList<boolean[]> stringSchedule,ArrayList<Boolean> boolRole){
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row_route,stringArray);

        //save the arrays in global var
        this.itemFrom = stringArray;
        this.itemTo = stringTo;
        this.itemHour = stringHour;
        this.itemSchedule = stringSchedule;
        this.itemRole = boolRole;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater customInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        final View customView = customInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_route, parent, false);

        String singleFrom = itemFrom.get(position);
        String singleTo = itemTo.get(position);
        String singleHour = itemHour.get(position);
        boolean singleRole = itemRole.get(position);

        //Get a string chain from the booleans routine from each user
        //String singleSchedule = ScheduleText(itemSchedule.get(position));

        //Get TextView from the custom row
        TextView customText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.fromText);
        TextView customTextTo = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.toText);
        TextView customTextHour = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.hourText);
        ImageView RoleImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.ImageRole);
        //TextView customTextSchedule = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.repeatText);

        //set the image of the role
        if(singleRole) {RoleImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.steer3);}
        else{ RoleImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.hand3);}


        //Give values from each position of the array
        customText.setText(singleFrom);
        customTextTo.setText(singleTo);
        customTextHour.setText(singleHour);


        //User want to edit a route
        ImageButton buttonEditTrip = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.ImageRole);

        return customView;

    }

}
```

Comment: you haven't include the most important part of the code: CustomAdapterRoute

Comment: how are you creating custom adapter?

Comment: Are you looking to purely increase the speed of your existing program, or better ways to implement?

Comment: Why you didnt create a model class and then create an array of that model class instead of using multiple arrays.

Comment: @Gavriel thanks just added the CustomAdapterRoute

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr im trying to make it load faster because when i have too many items it takes too much time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as I thought. You should use the holder pattern: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html to make it faster

Answer (score 1):

In the first piece of code, you're calling `response.body()` all the time (why don't get the body into a variable and reuse it?).

And then in the adapter, you are not reusing the `convertView`:

```
View customView;
if(convertView == null) {
   view = customInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_route, parent, false);
} else {
   customView = convertView;
}
```

Furthermore, you could also store the `LayoutInflater` as an instance variable of your adapter.

BTW the *custom* prefix is quite redundant, since everything you code is going to be *custom* by definition...

And the smooth scrolling link of the other answer (from @Gavriel) is important as well.